# ошибка при команде git init

Tags: git

работаю в терминале на vscode, пишу команду git init, но выдает это

```
Имя "git" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а  
также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1 
+ git init
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Может, кто-нибудь знает,в чем ошибка?

Comment: Ещё и powershell...

Comment: лучше писать команды в консольке git bash с powershell есть проблемки

Answer (score 6):

просто git не установлен или установлен как то очень странно (не прописан в пути переменной PATH). Я бы начал с установки гита https://git-scm.com/downloads